# Unexpected result with gnu-screen and call()

Tags: python, subprocess, gnu-screen

As a part of a bigger application I am trying to create an "screen" with python using the `subprocess.call()`.

Creating the screen with arguments `-d -m` should create it in background and not switch to it. If I run `screen -d -m -S test` on the command-line, it works as expected.

However if I try the following python-code:

```
cmd=["screen", "-d", "-m", "-S", "test"]
call(cmd,shell=True)
```

it jumps to the created screen.

Is there some difference in how call passes these arguments or runs the command?

Comment: If you're going to use `shell=True`, pass the arguments as a string (`"screen -d -m -S test"`) rather than an array (`['screen', '-d', '-m', '-S', 'test']`), as it's just going to get joined into a string and passed to the shell that way anyhow -- better not to pretend you have control over how the arguments are split to be passed to the `execv()` syscall when, by passing `shell=True`, you're actually giving that control up.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: you should make that an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried adding that line, because without the shell=True it doesn't seem to do anything. Passing a string with shell=True seems to work though

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd=["screen", "-d", "-m", "-S", "test", "bash"]
call(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (without the `shell=True`).

That is, with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import *
cmd=['screen', '-d', '-m', '-S', 'test']
call(cmd)
```

invocation correctly starts a backgrounded screen process:

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-cduffy.

$ ./screen-startup-test 
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        12161.test      (04/25/2012 03:47:32 PM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-cduffy.
```